# configuring VPS for Ruby on rails app...which version of Ruby to use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vps

I'm configuring my first VPS for my first ruby on rails app that I´m soon deploying to the web.

I'm following this documentation https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/16.04
it is going greate, but I just realised that my version of Ruby is `ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-darwin15]` and the recommended for the setup is ruby version 2.3.1.

So do I have to update the ruby version on my computer to 2.3.1 or is it ok to deploy an app build on ruby 2.2.3 to an server running version 2.3.1.

This might be a stupid question, but I just want to be sure because I lack experience and I´m setting up VPS for the first time.

p.s
The App soon to deployed is built in rails 4.2.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is totally fine if you use Ruby 2.2.3 in this circumstance because there's not much difference between Ruby 2.2.3 and 2.3.1, they are all minor versions of Ruby 2.0.0. In addition, Rails 4.2.5 works normally with both of them.